# after_setup_theme, Global Variable and Theme Customizer

Tags: theme-development, actions, theme-customizer, theme-options, globals

I am using a global variable that is defining in a function runs in `after_setup_theme`. This variable is not getting update changes in Theme Customizer.

**Let me explain this with an example:**

```
add_action( 'customize_register', "example_customizer_register");
function example_customizer_register($wp_customize) {

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'example_settings[example-variable]', array(
            'type'      => 'option',
            'default'   => false,
            'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_attr'
        ) );
        $wp_customize->add_control( 'example_settings[example-variable]', array(
            'label'    => 'Example Setting',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'section'  => 'title_tagline',
        ) );    
}

add_action("after_setup_theme", "example_after_setup_theme");
function example_after_setup_theme(){
    global $example_settings;
    $example_settings = get_option( "example_settings", array());
}


add_action("wp_head", "example_wp_head");
function example_wp_head(){
    global $example_settings;
    if (isset($example_settings["example-variable"]) && true == $example_settings["example-variable"]) {
        echo "Example Setting";
    }   
}
```

This code is adding an example setting in Site Identity section in Theme Customizer which is not working. If i change;

```
add_action("after_setup_theme", "example_after_setup_theme");
```

to

```
add_action("wp", "example_after_setup_theme");
```

Its working. But i need it in `after_setup_theme`. Any ideas for solution?

Comment: If your question has been answered, could you please accept the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that WP customizer submits the changes, but has not processed these yet at that point in time. If you cant wait for WP customizer to do it's thing by using a later action, here is a solution where you get the customized information and use it to overwrite the information we had.

```
add_action("after_setup_theme", "example_after_setup_theme");
function example_after_setup_theme(){
    global $example_settings;

    $option_key = "example_settings";
    $example_settings = get_option( $option_key, array() );

    // Check if wp_customize was posted
    if( isset( $_POST['wp_customize'] ) && $_POST['wp_customize'] == "on" && !empty( $_POST['customized'] ) ){

        // All the variables we need to look for
        $variables_to_find = array(
            'example-variable'
        );

        // Get the customized data
        $customized = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['customized'] ), true );

        // Make sure it's a proper array
        if( !empty( $customized ) && is_array( $customized ) ){

            // Lopp the customized items
            foreach ($variables_to_find as $sub_key) {

                // The key in the settings array
                $key = "{$option_key}[{$sub_key}]";

                // If a different value was posted
                if( array_key_exists( $key, $customized) ){

                    // Replace it in the current object with the one submitted
                    $example_settings[ $sub_key ] = $customized[ $key ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While its not perfect solution i hoped (variables have to be set), it gives right approach to problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [WordPress Codex :: Actions Run During a Typical Request](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request), you will notice that the action hook `after_setup_theme` is fired significantly earlier on than that of the action hook `wp`.

### What does this mean?

1. If you're able to access the global variable of `$example_settings`
   inside the action hook `wp`, then that means `$example_settings` has
   already been defined BEFORE the action hook of `wp` has been fired.
2. If you're NOT able to access the global variable of
   `$example_settings` inside the action hook of `after_setup_theme`,
   then that means the action hook `after_setup_theme` is fired
   BEFORE the `$example_settings` variable has been defined. Basically,
   your variable doesn't exist yet.

### How to fix this?

Define `$example_settings` in the hook `after_setup_theme` or before that hook is fired.

Comment: Well yeah.. Thats the question. Thanks for explaining the question more but its not the answer. A working solution will be appreciated

Comment: @ÜnsalKorkmaz I think this is the correct answer and I think you have not understood what Michael has explained. Note that actions is like events that happen one after one. If you are in a earlier event you can not access to data defined in a later events. Do you get it?

Comment: Yeah i got it. But this is a specific problem that has possibility to try it in a different way which i couldnt find and i hope someone can point it out.

Comment: Then I don't understand your problem :)

Comment: Check the solution. Thats what i am talking about. Different way. Thanks for your time